# create new Duration instance in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Flutter Docs say  " To create a new Duration object, use this class's single constructor giving the appropriate arguments: "

```
Duration fastestMarathon = new Duration(hours:2, minutes:3, seconds:2);
```

but when i try like this , my IDE says :
"1 required argument(s) expected, but 0 found.

```
Duration(dynamic durationHandler, {int days: 0, int hours: 0, int minutes: 0, int seconds: 0, int milliseconds: 0, int microseconds: 0}) → Duration
```

what is durationHandler ?

Comment: It's strange, because here https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/Duration-class.html is no mention about this. What version of flutter do you use?

Comment: Do you have a library that defines a duration class?

Comment: I am using Flutter 0.9.4 , Andrey

Comment: no library , I am new to Flutter and just trying to learn some concepts

Comment: Please post your full code. You have some other Duration class interfering like Rémi already mentioned.

Comment: My IDE still showing me this error , i don't know why this happen  , anyway if i click run it works perfectly ,thank you all for your replies